# how to add share button in my code - ANDROID

Tags: android, json, share

**hello frnds this is my code.....for json parsing how to add share button in this code..pls help me**

***This is my rss feed from json txt code.....
i want to add share button in this.....***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("link here");
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your share item in a separate xml file (optionally name it: name_of_xml_menu.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_share_white"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then use it on your activity's onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.name_of_xml_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

Now whenever that share icon is clicked, the onOptiosItemSelected is called:

```
      @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {

            openShareMenu();
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now my openShareMenu method contains a list of applications that would support sharing.

```
public void openShareMenu(){

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);//android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        String shareText = "this is the share text";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);


        //display apps that support the intent
        List<ResolveInfo> respondingApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri : respondingApps){
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,ri.activityInfo.name);
            Log.v(TAG,"-->"+ri.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
        }

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
    }
```

This should display the list of installed apps that would support the sharing feature.

EDIT://

this is the full code of the activity:
package com.test.shareproject;

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.name_of_xml_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {

            openShareMenu();
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void openShareMenu(){

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);//android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        String shareText = "this is the share text";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);


        //display apps that support the intent
        List<ResolveInfo> respondingApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,0);
        for(ResolveInfo ri : respondingApps){
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,ri.activityInfo.name);
            Log.v("TAG", "-->" + ri.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
        }

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Metasnarf i m new in android...so pls edit full codde...and send me in zip file.... pls my mail id - sahilyadav761@gmail.com

Comment: You can just add all the methods on your activity.

Comment: in my - Main Activity ?

Comment: Yes, then create a separate xml file (on your menu directory) for the menu.

Comment: I'll send you a zip file

Comment: i m sending my full code...pls edit properly & send me.......full code...give me your mail id

Comment: sent it... please accept my answer if it worked. This might help others. I'll be out for now.

Comment: mail was blocked by your email provider. I'll send you later.